# How to convert MsInfo32 into English from Hungarian?

Tags: msinfo32

I am currently facing an issue, where I need to send Ubisoft my MsInfo32, because I literally cannot play a game I bought from them.

However, the file I generate running msinfo with admin privileges, and saving the file, gives out Hungarian field names and field values.
So for example, this is just one block of code that MsInfo32 generates from an 8.9MB file:

```xml
<Data>
<Idő><![CDATA[2023. 03. 07. 4:30]]></Idő>
<Típus><![CDATA[Application Error]]></Típus>
<Részletek><![CDATA[A hibát okozó alkalmazás neve: UNO.exe, verzió: 2020.3.32.63664, időbélyeg: 0x6231489b&#x000d;&#x000a;A hibát okozó modul neve: Storm.dll, verzió: 2.5.6.0, időbélyeg: 0x62ac33c5&#x000d;&#x000a;Kivételkód: 0xc0000005&#x000d;&#x000a;Hiba pozíciója: 0x000000000061e9f9&#x000d;&#x000a;A hibát okozó folyamat azonosítója: 0x4d7c&#x000d;&#x000a;A hibát okozó alkalmazás indításának időpontja: 0x01d950a888ec6c69&#x000d;&#x000a;A hibát okozó alkalmazás elérési útja: C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Uno\UNO.exe&#x000d;&#x000a;A hibát okozó modul elérési útja: C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Uno\UNO_Data\Plugins\x86_64\Storm.dll&#x000d;&#x000a;Jelentés azonosítója: 4c20158f-93d8-4f1d-b44c-1ccdf56d139d&#x000d;&#x000a;A hibát okozó csomag teljes neve: &#x000d;&#x000a;A hibát okozó csomag relatív alkalmazásazonosítója:]]></Részletek>
</Data>
```

Notice the field names are in Hungarian, and also the field values are in Hungarian, and I presume they have a program that they load these MsInfo.nfo files into, and that program returns it's corrupted, since their program gets invalid data.
<Idő> in Hungarian means , <Típus> in Hungarian is , <Részletek> is  etc etc.

Is there a way to forcefully make Windows 10 generate MsInfo32.nfo in English? Because I am unable to continue with troubleshooting with Ubisoft currently, because of this. They keep sending me the corrupted MsInfo copy paste, but it's not corrupted, its just in Hungarian.

I tried doing the same things as the customer support sent me, but they do not accept it. Their copy paste message is the following:

> The file you have sent is in incorrect format, these steps include
> modifications to make sure this one is no longer corrupt:
>
> 1. From Windows, click Start, then select Run (XP), Start Search (Vista), Search Programs and Files (Win 7), or Search (Win 8).(You can
>    also press the Windows key and the "R" key at the same time.)
> 2. In the Open box, type 'msinfo32' (without the quotes) and click OK.
> 3. When the program comes up, open the Software Environment section on the left side and select Windows Error Reporting.
> 4. Make sure that the Windows Error Reporting has also completely loaded prior to saving.
> 5. At the top, click on File. Click on Save.
> 6. Click the "Save" button to save the file as nfo file to your desktop.
>
> If you receive an error stating that the file is too large, you will
> need to compress it.
>
> 1. Right-click the file.
> 2. Hover over the Send to option, and then select the Compressed (zipped) folder.
> 3. A new ZIP file will be created.
>
> Once received, we will examine your system information and get back to
> you as soon as we can with a possible solution to your problem.
>
> Regards, Ubisoft Support

Please, if you can, help me. Would appreciate it very much. I was not able to find any source on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your windows display language in the settings (Time and Language).

You have to logout and re-login to do the change, then start `msinfo32` and export the file. Afterwards you can change the language back to hungarian and re-login.

Maybe you have to install a Language Pack in the Microsoft Store (called "...Local Experience Pack" there), you can install new language packs also directly from the dialog where you select the display language (below at "Preferred languages")